# use of wild card for set of first letters notworking mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

This is the query I'm using but it's returning an empty table

```
select ename from new_schema.employee where ename like '[svg]%' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: select ename  from new_schema.employee where ename like '[svg]%' ;

Comment: this is the query i used but it is returning me empty table

Comment: If a `SELECT` query returns no results then there were no matching records.  What information do you have which would indicate otherwise?

Comment: yes iam using mysql and i have populated data with the name starting with 's','v','g' so is there any other way to get the names starting with those letters at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Microsoft SQL Server syntax for the pattern.

MySQL only supports standard wildcards for the `LIKE` predicate. I.e. `%` and `_`, but not square brackets.

You can use a regular expression instead of `LIKE` to search for a character class:

```
select ename from new_schema.employee where ename REGEXP '^[svg].*' ;
```

You should keep in mind that every vendor of SQL database does things differently, and implements their own ideas about extensions to standard SQL. You need to refer to documentation for the brand and version you are using, and don't expect features that work in one brand (Microsoft) to work the same in another brand (MySQL).

Comment: thank you so much Bill now i got it